# Getting Warning in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I get this error when I access URL http://localhost:8080/RiteshMVC/hey:

> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
>   WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringDemo/] in
>   DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringMVCDemo'

I have loaded all my jars with commons-logging.

This is my code.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

     <display-name>RiteshMVC</display-name>
     <servlet>
       <servlet-name>RiteshMVCDemo</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet                   </servlet-class>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>

     <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>RiteshMVCDemo</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping> 

</web-app>
```

RiteshMVCDemo-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="ritesh.dhoke" />

  <bean  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

Controllers.java

```
package ritesh.dhoke;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hey")
public class Controllers 
{
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView Hey(){

        return new ModelAndView("hello", "User", "This is cool man");
    }
}
```

hello.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
This is me ${User}
</body>
</html>
```

Please help. Seems to be perfect but I don't know whats wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your web app getting deployed successfully?? I am not asking about request and response, only web app deployment.

Comment: Sorry sir i am new to springs..i dont have any idea about deployment.
when i run the project it shows HTTP Status 404- The request resources not available.
in url i pass /hey it shows same msg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `web.xml` file configuration, you have not mention spring context configuration file location. So spring will not be able to find `RiteshMVCDemo-servlet.xml` file. Also you have not registered for `ContextLoaderListener`. Please use below code snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app ...>
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<display-name>RiteshMVC</display-name>
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>RiteshMVCDemo</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/RiteshMVCDemo-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>RiteshMVCDemo</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

`root-context.xml` and `RiteshMVCDemo-servlet.xml` should be in the location as mentioned in the configuration

Comment: If you still face the issue, please post your error stack shown in the console window of IDE you are using.

Comment: after updating web.xml

SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)

Comment: Okay remove the context-param tag completely. Try then tell me what happen.

Comment: Actually your web app don't have root-context.xml file so that's why it is giving that error. Tell me if it works or not.